# Is there Django form field or widget that appends Radio and CharField

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-widget

I'm trying to create a Django form fields that has radio choices and "other" choice that is a text field.
[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxQV0.png)
I tried [this](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2014/05/implementing-multiple-radio-select.html) but its from 2014 and it's not working.
Can you give me an idea how to fix this code or how can I create a custom widget that will do the job.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML radio button form syntax and insert your Django templates.

```
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="test" name="test"
             checked>
      <label for="test">{{ template }}</label>
<input type="radio" name="reason" value="">{{ template }} <input type="text" name="..." />
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm creating a survey with questions app and I need to have different types of questions
`QUESTION_TYPES = (
        (TEXT, _("text (multiple line)")),
        (SHORT_TEXT, _("short text (one line)")),
        (RADIO, _("radio")),
        (SELECT, _("select")),
        (SELECT_MULTIPLE, _("Select Multiple")),
        (SELECT_IMAGE, _("Select Image")),
        (INTEGER, _("integer")),
        (FLOAT, _("float")),
        (DATE, _("date")),
        (RADIO_AND_TEXT, _("Radio and other")),
    )
`
In order of this to work i need it to be either field or widget. Thank you.